# Program not running input file

Tags: c++, linux

Here's my code:

```
int i,u,v = 0;
scanf("%d%d",&N,&M );
Edge.resize(N+1);
for( i=1;i<=M;i++){
    scanf("%d%d",&u,&v );
    Edge[u].push_back( v );
}
```

So, i'm reading input that i type. Example:

```
6 7
1 2
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 5
5 6
3 4
```

But to be easier to input i've compiled my file.

```
g++ -O3 -ansi -Wall main.cpp -lm -o proj
```

And inserted those numbers in a file called: "tin1.in". And tried to run in terminal with command:

```
/.proj tin1.in
```

If i input manually, it works perfectly, but when I try to run automatically, it doesn't do anything it appears to be running forever. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need spaces between the `%d`s.

Comment: I think you meant `./proj <tin1.in`

Comment: I've inserted the spaces and still nothing. Edit: It's that Matt McNabb. Thanks

Comment: Your program does not read from the `tin1.in`. It still reads from `stdin`. Change your execution to `cat tin1.in | ./proj`

Answer (score 0):

Your program "does not do anything" because it is has run up to the `scanf` line and is blocked waiting for standard input to be received from the command terminal.

`./proj tin1.in` only sets the "first" element of `argv` to "tin1.in".

This parameter does automatically not open the file `tin1.in` and read it.  It is up to your program to read and parse `argv` and interpret what the arguments mean and open files or take other actions, but [I assume] your program does not include any code to do that so nothing happens with the `tin1.in` information.

There is a built-in way in unix-like OS to redirect stdin. If you wish to redirect stdin to a file, you need to run proj with the command `./proj <tin1.in` or `cat tin1.in | ./prog` as recommended in comments.